# MySQL - Filter records which date is biggest

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have this mysql select query:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM campaign_statistic AS s INNER JOIN campaign AS c ON s.campaign_id = c.campaign_id 
WHERE c.campaign_id = 51 
AND date(s.created_date) BETWEEN date(c.start_date) AND date(c.end_date)
```

and getting this result:

```
id  campaign_id     instagram_id    media_id                        has_tag     comments_count  likes_count     created_date            status
**  ***********     ************    ****************************    ********    *************   ***********     *******************     ******
1   51              1230544324      957801995790641919_1230544324   together    1               16              2015-11-01 13:10:29     1
2   51              1230544324      957799073015065299_1230544324   together    2               11              2015-11-01 13:10:29     1
3   51              1230544324      957790310736521811_1230544324   together    5               20              2015-11-01 13:10:29     1
4   51              1230544324      957801995790641919_1230544324   together    1               16              2015-11-02 13:10:29     1
5   51              1230544324      957799073015065299_1230544324   together    2               11              2015-11-02 13:10:29     1
6   51              1230544324      957790310736521811_1230544324   together    5               20              2015-11-02 13:10:29     1
7   51              1230544324      957801995790641919_1230544324   together    1               16              2015-11-03 13:10:29     1
8   51              1230544324      957799073015065299_1230544324   together    2               11              2015-11-03 13:10:29     1
9   51              1230544324      957790310736521811_1230544324   together    5               20              2015-11-03 13:10:29     1
```

but I am trying to get only those records which `created_date` is biggest from above result and biggest `created_date` is `2015-11-03`.

I need this result:

```
id  campaign_id     instagram_id    media_id                        has_tag     comments_count  likes_count     created_date            status
**  ***********     ************    ****************************    ********    *************   ***********     *******************     ******
7   51              1230544324      957801995790641919_1230544324   together    1               16              2015-11-03 13:10:29     1
8   51              1230544324      957799073015065299_1230544324   together    2               11              2015-11-03 13:10:29     1
9   51              1230544324      957790310736521811_1230544324   together    5               20              2015-11-03 13:10:29     1
```

Any idea or suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try running this:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM campaign_statistic AS s INNER JOIN campaign AS c ON s.campaign_id = c.campaign_id 
WHERE c.campaign_id = 51 
AND date(s.created_date) BETWEEN date(c.start_date) AND date(c.end_date)
    AND date(s.created_date) = (
    SELECT date(max(s.created_date)) 
FROM campaign_statistic AS s INNER JOIN campaign AS c ON s.campaign_id = c.campaign_id 
WHERE c.campaign_id = 51 
AND date(s.created_date) BETWEEN date(c.start_date) AND date(c.end_date))
```

Comment: @php-baby this gets optimised automatically when explain-plan is created.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using `not exists` to get the rows with the greatest `created_date` per `campagin_id`

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM campaign_statistic AS s INNER JOIN campaign AS c ON s.campaign_id = c.campaign_id 
WHERE c.campaign_id = 51 
AND date(s.created_date) BETWEEN date(c.start_date) AND date(c.end_date)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM campaign_statistic AS s2
    INNER JOIN campaign c2 ON s2.campaign_id = c2.campaign_id
    WHERE s2.campaign_id = s.campaign_id
    AND s2.created_date > s.created_date
)
```

Comment: perhaps throw Fuzzy a bone by giving him a sqlfiddle

Comment: @PHPBaby, was missing an inner join in the subquery, try again

Comment: I have changed `AND s2.created_date > s.created_date` to `AND s2.id > s.id` but still getting empty result. `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0250 sec)`

Comment: @PHPBaby I think the problem was the missing  `inner join` in the subquery and not changing `AND s2.created_date > s.created_date to AND s2.id > s.id`

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do this with a subquery, but I think the easiest is using variables because of the join and the filtering:

```
SELECT cs.*
FROM (SELECT s.* ,
             (@rn := if(@d = date(s.created_date), @rn,
                        if(@d := date(s.created_date), @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                       )
             ) rn
      FROM campaign_statistic s INNER JOIN
           campaign c
           ON s.campaign_id = c.campaign_id CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @d := 0, @rn := 0) params
      WHERE c.campaign_id = 51 AND
            date(s.created_date) BETWEEN date(c.start_date) AND date(c.end_date)
      ORDER BY s.created_date desc
     ) cs
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The variables are doing, essentially, a `dense_rank()` on the `created_date` column.

I would suggest writing the `WHERE` clause as:

```
      WHERE s.campaign_id = 51 AND
            s.created_date >= DATE(c.start_date) AND
            s.created_date < DATE_ADD(DATE(c.end_date), interval 1 day)
```

Then I think the query can take advantage of an index on `campaign_statistic(campaign_id, created_date)`.