# MySQL Loop to execute query that uses incrementing variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that uses a variable in its where clause:

```
SET @id = 1;

SELECT  
    id,
    value
FROM myTable
WHERE id = @id;
```

I would like to run the query for `@id` values 1 through 100,  and then union (or somehow combine) all the loop results into one result set. Is this possible in MySQL, and if so, what is a good approach?

Answer (score 1):

Why would use use a variable for this?  Just use a simple `where` clause:

```
select id, value
from myTable
where id between 1 and 100;
```

If, instead, you really want the first 100 rows by id, then use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select id, value
from myTable
order by id
limit 100;
```

Comment: The query is simplified example of a more complex query that wouldn't work with this fix

Comment: @bsapaka . . . Ask another question that is more representative of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a subquery to get the variable.

And put the `where` outside

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
    SELECT  
        @rownumber := if(@rownumber, @rownumber + 1, @rownumber + 1)  AS id,
        value
    FROM myTable
    CROSS JOIN (select @rownumber := 0) r
    ) as T
WHERE id < 100;
```

Comment: the order of evaluation is not guarenteed and this can cause problems with using variables in a select query. it is expressly recommended to not do

Comment: @JohnRuddell Im not 100% sure about this issue. what I found is something like this `@rownumber := if(@rownumber, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)  AS id,` fix it?

Comment: [you should read their docs on this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html) and read the part with `the order of evaluation`

Comment: Yes, I read it before. What is the part explaining this problem?

Comment: search for the part where it talks about the order of evaluation

Comment: `As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and may change based on the elements contained within a given statement; in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between releases of the MySQL Server.`

Comment: @JohnRuddell I see they said is a problem, But not see an example of what is wrong or a way to fix it. So still not understand it :(. I just use the example I saw from Gordon http://stackoverflow.com/a/33462568/3470178

Comment: if you use one variable then the order is guaranteed for now. not certain about future releases though. in general it would be best to steer away from a row by row calculation...

Comment: the problem is the @rownumber could or could not be set correctly in the row evaluation

Comment: @JohnRuddell Maybe Im more than a visual person. Can you point to a correct sample of emulate the row_number()?